# 3.7V to 7.5V step up circuit

Tags: power, batteries, current, power-consumption, step-up

I need a circuit which can step up the voltage from my 3.7V Li Ion battery to 7.5V.

The current requirements are pretty small (up to 50mA max), but I have a latching solenoid which requires a short 7.5V pulse @ 350mA and so the step up circuit must be able to supply this too. I designed one based on the MC34063A but the Ipk value was around 2A and I don't think the IC can cope with that.

Would anyone be able to recommend a differnt IC that I could use. Power consumption is the main concern since it's a battery powered project and so ideally I want the power consumption of the IC to be proportional to the output power, i.e. I don't want it to draw a lot of power while it's only using up to 50mA in order to cope with the larger pulse.

Comment: [Figure 10 in the datasheet](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/MC34063A-D.PDF) shows you how to get more current from a MC34063. But even though your Ipk is 2A, for what length of time does your latching solenoid need that current? Some number of milliseconds I assume? Choosing a suitable output cap on your boost circuit should be able to provide for that.

Comment: *Questions seeking recommendations for specific products or places to purchase them are off-topic as they are rarely useful to others and quickly obsolete.*

Comment: @brhans Thanks! I must have missed that in the datasheet but I'll check it out. That's a good point also. It only requires a 15ms pulse so maybe the right capacitor will do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.5 amps needn't be the limit when using the [MC34063A](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/mc34063a.pdf?ts=1610952821230&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FMC34063A%253Futm_source%253Dgoogle%2526utm_medium%253Dcpc%2526utm_campaign%253Dapp-null-null-GPN_EN-cpc-pf-google-wwe%2526utm_content%253DMC34063A%2526ds_k%253DMC34063A%2526DCM%253Dyes%2526gclid%253DCj0KCQiA3Y-ABhCnARIsAKYDH7tnW8AcaoZPIbroo9FGZoG1eXOqfaEv_vjCTCdMwqlvlG0NI0tKeXAaAqJjEALw_wcB%2526gclsrc%253Daw.ds) chip: -

[image]

But, even if the peak current is limited why not run in CCM mode? If your input voltage needs to be as low as 3 volts (for example) and you used a 15 μH inductor, I can't see the peak inductor current exceeding 1.75 amps: -

[image]

The above calculation is based on producing 8.1 volts (7.5 volts after a non-ideal rectifier) at the output and driving a 20 ohm load from a 3 volt input supply. \$I_{PEAK}\$ is 1.723 amps. Switching frequency is 100 kHz.

I've also assumed that once the output capacitor is charged up to the required output voltage that it will "soak up" the 350 mA pulses to a certain extent. In that respect, I've made the assumption that the output current will average at 375 mA. The MC34063A has a current limit facility so I don't really see it having a problem.

Calculator can be found [**here**](http://www.stades.co.uk/Boost%20converter/Boost%20calculator.html).

If you used a 22 μH inductor, the peak inductor current is 1.523 amps.

If you use a 33 μH inductor, the peak inductor current is 1.380 amps: -

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Why not use ?
[3V relay @ 200mA for 50ms](https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/filter/power-relays-over-2-amps/188?s=N4IgjCBcoOwExVAYygMwIYBsDOBTANCAPZQDaIcADAMyWUCsIAuoQA4AuUIAyuwE4BLAHYBzEAF9CANhiNoIFJAw4CxMiGpTq8SiEKbtcCCxAcuvQaImEwATgActxArRY8hEpHK6TZyD35hMUkQAFoEeUV%2BAFdVT3JGX05-CRC5UFYoMDZMyDh6EKlnAQATLhkINmSQAFUhAXYAeVQAWVx0bGi%2BXD0QdgBPVh7-EuwUcXEgA) instead of a
350mA 7.5V relay for 50 ms
that takes over 800mA on battery
and more to start up..
, such as boost regulators do and this is > 2x voltage so battery current will be > 2x
.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'm not actually using a relay though. I'm using a H-bridge IC to drive the solenoid which requires 7.5V @ 350mA.

Comment: Can U post the solenoid spec with impedance and duration?